# How to retrieve the Hessian after a logistic regression in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, hessian-matrix

I am using the package scikit-learn to compute a logistic regression on a moderately large data set (300k rows, 2k cols. That's pretty large to me!).

Now, since scikit-learn does not produce confidence intervals, I am calculating them myself. To do so, I need to compute and invert the Hessian matrix of the logistic function evaluated at the minimum. Since scikit-learn already computes the Hessian while optimizing, it'd be efficient if I could retrieve it.

**In `sklearn.classification.LogisticRegression`, Is there any way to retrieve the Hessian evaluated at the minimum value?**

Note: This is an intermediate step, and I actually only need the diagonal entries of the inverse of the Hessian. If anyone has a more straightforward way to get there, I'd love to learn it.

Comment: `Since scikit-learn already computes the Hessian while optimizing` - A link for that would probably helpful.